# Trouble with .apply() Methods with 'int' columns

Tags: python, pandas

Problem with this code using 'pandas' library in python:

Trying to apply the .apply () method in a column that is an 'int'.
Before I made a def and tried to use (if, else);

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("'> =' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'", 'occurred at index A View to a Kill')
```

I tried to pass the 'Year' column from int64 to 'Str'. but it gives me almost the same error.

```
bond = pd.read_csv('jamesbond.csv', index_col = 'Film')
bond.sort_index(inplace = True)
bond.head(3)



def classic_modern(row):
    year = [0]

    if year >= 1990 :
        return 'The movie is modern'
    else :
        return 'The movie is old one'
bond.apply(classic_modern , axis = 1)
```

Comment: use `numpy.where`

Comment: Don't you mean ``year = row[0]``?

Comment: `numpy.where(bond[column name] >= 1990, 'The movie is modern', 'The movie is old one')`

Comment: Thanks so much @Nihal but I'm practicing with only 'pandas' library and inside it: .apply () method.

That's why the interest comes out that way :)

Comment: @ErikXIII thanks so much , this was the solution .

Answer (score 0):

This line initalizes a list with 1 value `0`:

```
year = [0]
```

Next up you compare this list with an integer, causing your error:

```
if year >= 1990:  # if [0] >= 1990
```

Comment: yes yes yes , i just to found the solution , is : year = row[0] and i had like year = [0]